# Upload Tag Favicons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Is there a way to upload a "favicon" (that's the most relevant term I can put to it, let me know if there's an official name for it!) for a tag?

If not, can there be? (Unless it would be too legally tricky to do so?)

I think tags look better with images (like the browser tags have) and it would be a tag-wiki edit so it would require approval, I think.

Comment: Icons appear to be reserved for sponsored tags.

Comment: Well, that explains why they allowed Internet Explorer to have one..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are talking about [sponsored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/sponsored-tags/info).

These are not available to the general public - one needs to show affiliation/ownership of the technology that a tag is associated with (such as Azure and Microsoft, or Chrome and Google).

As the name suggests, a company that chooses to sponsor a tag, does so by paying for it.

Comment: So that means we can't put the Java logo on the JavaScript tag to mess with people? :(

Comment: @RUJordan - apart from the fact that we would never "mess with people" in such a way? Yes. If Sun wanted to sponsor Java, they could. If ECMA or Mozilla wanted to sponsor JavaScript they probably could.

Comment: Trust me, that was just a joke. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, **Sun** will never be able to sponsor Java :)

Comment: @Oded I think you meant *Oracle*...just saying...